# If $\vec{v}+i\vec{w}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then so is $\vec{v}-i\vec{w}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A_{n\times n}$ is a real matrix with eigenvector $\vec{v}+i\vec{w}$ and associated eigenvalue $p+iq$. Show that $\vec{v}-i\vec{w}$ is also an eigenvector with associated eigenvalue $p-iq$.

I would appreciate references or any information revealing how this problem can be solved.

Comment: Perform complex conjugation on both sides of $A(\vec v+i\vec w) = (p+iq)(\vec v+i\vec w)$. What do you get?

Comment: @Carley Just note that complex conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ that leaves real numbers unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If ${\bf v} + i {\bf w}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $p + i q$, we have
$$A ({\bf v} + i {\bf w}) = (p + i q)({\bf v} + i {\bf w})$$
and we want to conclude that
$$A ({\bf v} - i {\bf w}) = (p - i q)({\bf v} - i {\bf w}).$$
What simple operation transforms the first equation into the second?

Comment: It looks like we're just taking the conjugate of both sides. But is $A$ unaffected by this operation?

Comment: @Carley the entries of $A$ are real :)

Comment: @AWertheim oh course! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume $v$ and $w$ are real vectors. Then
$$A(v + iw) = Av + iAw = (p+iq)(v+iw) = (pv - qw) + i(qv + pw)$$
means that
$$Av = pv - qw$$

Can you continue on your own?